# How to Click on specific button in web browser

Tags: c#, browser

there are about 10 button with almost same HTML input class in my web page but I want to perform virtual click on specific button.

How do I do this ?

Here are some of them :

```
<input name="" value="ذخيره يا چاپ&nbsp;" onclick="saveOrPrint()" class="fieldbutton" type="button">  
<input name="" value="ارسال&nbsp;" onclick="return sendEmail()" class="fieldbutton" type="button">  
<input name="" tabindex="" value="نمایش رکوردهای انتخاب شده" onclick="displaySelectedRows()" disabled="disabled" class="fieldbutton" type="button">
```

I want to click on first button. This code didn't work :

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("type") == "button" &&
        element.GetAttribute("class") == "fieldbutton")
    {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

All Codes :

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement textElement = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("simpleSearch.value")[0];
        textElement.SetAttribute("value", "9789643775070");
        HtmlElement searchtype = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("simpleSearch.indexFieldId")[0];
        searchtype.SetAttribute("value", "221091");
        HtmlElement documenttype =
            webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("bibliographicLimitQueryBuilder.biblioDocType")[0];
        documenttype.SetAttribute("value", "BF");
        HtmlElement button =
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
                .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("type") == "submit");
        button.InvokeMember("click");

        HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
        {
            var value = element.GetAttribute("value");
            if (value.Trim().ToLower().Equals("ذخيره يا چاپ"))
            {
                element.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
    private void btn_LibraryManagement_NewCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@"http://opac.nlai.ir/opac-prod/search/searchBF.do");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }
```

edit :
**This is not my website, and I can't change anything on this site.**
*Help is appreciated*

Comment: I used to scroll down to button with sending `PageDown` key to WebBrowser and move mouse pointer over the button and click.

Comment: It's funny, but never useful for programmers. Because the website `may change` or `Resolution` of client can make this wrong. Isn't there any safe way to do this ?

Comment: Yes, since my application's user was myself, I did it that way ;)

Comment: Isn't there any way to find elements using value or method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use value. Try this :

```
HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"); 

foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)

{
    var value = element.GetAttribute("value");

    if (value.Trim().ToLower().Equals("ذخيره يا چاپ"))
        {
           element.InvokeMember("click");
        }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't change `type` to `value` ?

Comment: I already use this code in another format, but it didn't work. I think the reason may be this : the value is unicode not char and also these are nodes not attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I find the problem but I can't solve it ! I have some other code before this in `webBrowser_DocumentCompleted` and I click on some other button (like this) before this. when a button clicked, the page changed but Further Code runs on old page ... and make wrong result. How can I solve this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @ProgramChef please post your codes in your question field with details.

Comment: @ProgramChef I updated the code with value.Trim().ToLower().Equals() method. Try that.

Comment: I tried this, It should work true, but the reason is : This code run on old form before the last button click finished. I want to run this code after web browser document completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to add some unique "ID" (attribute in html) for each button when you are building the page? After that will be much more easy to identify unique actions.

Like

```
<input id="print" name="" value="ذخيره يا چاپ&nbsp;" onclick="saveOrPrint()" class="fieldbutton" type="button">
<input  id="emailing" name="" value="ارسال&nbsp;" onclick="return sendEmail()" class="fieldbutton" type="button">
<input  id="selectedrows" name="" tabindex="" value="نمایش رکوردهای انتخاب شده" onclick="displaySelectedRows()" disabled="disabled" class="fieldbutton" type="button">
```

than inside your foreach, for example:

```
if (element.GetAttribute("type") == "button" &&
    element.GetAttribute("id") == "emailing")
{
    element.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Comment: It isn't my website !! If I can control this site, actually I and Id or name to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add id to each  tag and call the click event based on button id rather then based on class.

Comment: It isn't my website !! If I can control this site, actually I and Id or name to do this.